# call javascript function on the click event of hyperlink

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, servlets

I am developing a web application using JSP and Servlet.

I am trying to call javascript function on the click event of hyperlink, and with that I am also passing some parameters to servlet using query string.

```
<td> <a href="#?id=<%=data[i][0]%>&protID=<%=data[i][1]%>&seqNo=<%=data[i][2]%>" onclick="getValues();" >Edit</a></td>
```

javascript function:

```
<script>
function getValues()
{
    var url = document.URL;
    var planID = url.split("=");
    var pID = planID[1].split("&");

    var remURI = url.split("&");
    var protID = remURI[1].split("=");

    var s = remURI[2].split("=");

    document.getElementById('txtPlanID').value=pID[0];
    document.getElementById('txtProtID').value=protID[1];
    document.getElementById('txtSeqNo').value=s[1];

//show("block");
return false;
}
</script>
```

But the problem is that I have to click twice on hyperlink to get desired result.
I think onClick event is executing before sending query string.
Please let me know if there is anything wrong in source code.

Thanks in advance.....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<td> <a href="#" onclick="getValues('<%=data[i][0]%>','<%=data[i][1]%>','<%=data[i][2]%>');" >Edit</a></td>


function getValues(pID,protID,eq)
{

document.getElementById('txtPlanID').value=pID;
document.getElementById('txtProtID').value=protID;
document.getElementById('txtSeqNo').value=eq;

//show("block");
return false;
```

}

simply pass values while calling javascript get use it

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<a href="javascript:return getValues('<%=data[i][0]%>','<%=data[i][1]%>','<%=data[i][2]%>');">Edit</a>
```

JS

```
function getValues(value1, value2, value3)
{
    document.getElementById('txtPlanID').value = value1;
    document.getElementById('txtProtID').value= value2;
    document.getElementById('txtSeqNo').value= value3;

    return false;
}
```

Comment: do not use copy paste of other user's

Answer (score 0):

Provide the clicked link as argument to the function:

```
onclick="getValues(this);return false;"
```

then use the href-attribute of the link as url:

```
function getValues(link)
{
    var url = link.href;
    //more code
}
```