# On clicking a specific hyperlink, should I get value corresponding to it?

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, hyperlink, tags

Within a for-loop, I am creating a number of hyperlinks, eg: list of students . Now on clicking name of one student, I should  get their details displayed on next page which i will be able to fetch using name, but how to get that name which I have clicked?

I have tried to to create one form and giving onclick event as described here: [call javascript function on the click event of hyperlink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14020355/call-javascript-function-on-the-click-event-of-hyperlink)

Thank you in advance

editing.jsp

```
<td width="149" >Students:</td> <% 
            for(int i=0;i<fr.length;i++){
                %>
                <form action ="editing.jsp" id="testform" method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="name" value="<% out.write(fr[i][1]);%>" />
                </form>

                <td > <a onclick="test()"><% out.write(fr[i][0]);
            //  out.write();


                 String s1=fr[i][1];
                    HttpSession ss1=request.getSession();
                    ss1.setAttribute("eid",s1);
                    %></a></td>
            <% }    %>
```

this is displayed on one part of the page and on other part

```
<div id="name"><h3><% 

    HttpSession sss=request.getSession();
        String eid=(String)sss.getAttribute("eid");
        eid=request.getParameter("eid");
    ConnectionWithPerson conwithper = new ConnectionWithPerson();
    String name = conwithper.getName(eid);
    out.write(name);
    int num=0;
     %></h3></div>
<table border="1">
<tr>
<td><div id="photo">
    <img src="http://d.gr-assets.com/users/1392364678p5/28682812.jpg" />
</div>
</td>
<td>
<div id = "details">
        <ul><% String[] b=conwithper.otherDetails(eid);%>
            <li>Email-id:&nbsp;<% out.write(eid); %></li>
            <li>Gender:&nbsp;<%
            //out.write(b[1]);%></li>
            <li>Occupation:<%
            //out.write(b[5]);%></li>
            <li>Birthday:&nbsp;</li>
            <li>Address:&nbsp;<%
            //out.write(b[0]);%></li>

        </ul>
</div>
```

I tried creating session but it displayed only last students details to me, i then tried using form but it was getting messed with session code. i cannot remove session code as i am fetching it from previous page.

Comment: Can you display your attempt(s) and explain the what doesn't appear to be working within your attempt(s). No source code = nothing to work with. Thanks. *Also any relevant source code is always helpful*

Comment: Share your source code, pls. That will help us understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: when you are calling the function, pass the 'name' as argument. Then you can use it in function to open the details page. You can share a snippet for us to understand better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new page don't redirect on same page say displayprofiles

```
<td >Student:
    <% 
            for(int i=0;i<ch.length;i++){
                 %><a href="displayprofiles.jsp?&ei=<%out.write(ch[i][1]);%>"><%
                out.write(ch[i][0]);%></a><%
            }   
    %></td>
```

on displayprofiles.jsp

```
String ei=request.getParameter("ei");
```